# Bigdecimal Not giving exact output in Java

Tags: java

Im adding three big decimals here, but it should give me accurate answer. I'm having two strings here and then converting to big decimal. Please dont ask why Im using strings. There is some business where I will get these values as string then I need to convert. Please find the code

```
BigDecimal a= new BigDecimal(100.05); --> This value I receive from web service. Its a decimal value from the service. 
    String b= "100.05";
    String c= "200.03";
    System.out.println(a.add(new BigDecimal(b).add(new BigDecimal(c))));
```

Output it gives

400.1299999999999971578290569595992565155029296875

Where as it should be 400.13

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is your use of `new BigDecimal(100.05)`. The value of `a` is then 100.0499999999999971578290569595992565155029296875.

If you had specified that value as a string instead, all would be well:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("100.05");
String b = "100.05";
String c = "200.03";
System.out.println(a.add(new BigDecimal(b).add(new BigDecimal(c))));
// Output: 400.13
```

If you *only* have the input as a `double`, you can use `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` instead of calling the constructor:

```
BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.valueOf(100.05); // a is now exactly 100.05
```

Compare the [`BigDecimal(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-) documentation:

> Translates a double into a BigDecimal which is the exact decimal representation of the double's binary floating-point value. (...)

With that of [`BigDecimal.valueOf(Double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf-double-):

> Translates a double into a `BigDecimal`, using the double's canonical string representation provided by the `Double.toString(double)` method.
>
> **Note:** This is generally the preferred way to convert a `double` (or `float`) into a `BigDecimal`, as the value returned is equal to that resulting from constructing a `BigDecimal` from the result of using `Double.toString(double)`.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Got it. Made a small mistake

Answer (score 4):

```
new BigDecimal(100.05)
```

This gives 100.0499999999999971578290569595992565155029296875, because 100.05 cannot be represented exactly as a `double`.

You have to use string here as well:

```
new BigDecimal("100.05")
```

As you get this value from a web-service, you probably convert it from a `String` to a `float`/`double`. If this is the case, just skip that conversion step.

If your web-service stub maps the return value to `float`/`double`, you can consider mapping it to a `String` directly and then feed it to `BigDecimal` constructor, like this:

```
double v = 100.05; // Value from web service
BigDecimal a= new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(v));
String b= "100.05";
String c= "200.03";
System.out.println(a.add(new BigDecimal(b).add(new BigDecimal(c))));
```

[Live Example](https://ideone.com/HrgXGr)

That works because the string will only contain as many digits as are needed to differentiate the almost-100.05 value from the next value on either side that can be represented, and so we get the string `"100.05"`, which then `BigDecimal` can process correctly.

Comment: It should be noted that the documentation of the BigDecimal class actually mentions the problems of the constructor using double value: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double) - especially: *Therefore, it is generally recommended that the String constructor be used in preference to this one.*

Comment: @Yakhoob I mean `a` value

Answer (score 0):

You can format the answer to Decimal places using `String.format` and specifiying how many digits.

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", a.add(new BigDecimal(b).add(new BigDecimal(c)))));
```